# Distribute the nodes of an Elasticache cluster across different AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

The following list shows there are 10 shards in the Elasticache cluster. And each cluster has two nodes, they are all in one REplicationGroup. Auto-failover is enabled and Multi-AZ is disabled.

However, only `us-east-1a` and `us-east-1a` are used. `us-east-1c` and `us-east-1d` are not used. How to evenly distribute the nodes to the four AZs? (AWS cli or console)

```
 "CacheClusterId","PreferredAvailabilityZone","ReplicationGroupId"
 'abcde1234-0001-001', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0002-001', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0001-002', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0002-002', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0003-001', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0003-002', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0004-001', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0004-002', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0005-001', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0005-002', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0006-001', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0006-002', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0007-001', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0007-002', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0008-001', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0008-002', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0009-001', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0009-002', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0010-001', 'us-east-1a', 'abcde1234'
 'abcde1234-0010-002', 'us-east-1b', 'abcde1234'
```

Should Multi-AZ be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Multi-AZ enablement, only tell ElastiCache service to enforce cross-az between primary and replicas and is useful for minimizing downtime during Availability Zone failure. When multi-az is enabled, elasticache is committed to 99.99% availability SLA. Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/AutoFailover.html for more information.

Regarding your issue, ElastiCache default behavior is to evenly distribute nodes across the AZs given as part of the cache subnet group. From your prints it looks like your subnet group is compound of 2 AZs - us-east-1a and us-east-1b. An easy validation is to check the subnet group in the AWS console or [describe](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elasticache/describe-cache-subnet-groups.html) it running

```
aws elasticache describe-cache-subnet-groups --cache-subnet-group-name <my-subnet-group>
```

If you desire a custom placement over the AZs (as oppose to the default evenly distribution), ElastiCache gives you the ability to determine for each node, primary or replica, a specific AZ placement. Keep in mind that if you enable Multi-AZ, you must place primary and his replicas on different AZs or the creation will fail.